# jsf.ajax.request to call JSF bean to execute a method

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to call JSF Bean method from the javascript using ajax.requst. Share button from the below XHTML file will execute a javascript which will run the below ajax function. But i am getting the below error. I need help in executing the ajax request in this route, i believe there would be several alternatives but i want it to work it this way for now.

**javascript**

```
$('#shareButton').livequery("click", function () {
............................
.................

           jsf.ajax.request('commandLink',null,{execute: 'commandLink',render: 'topic_guid'});
...................
.............})
```

**XHTML**

```
        <f:form id="testForm" prependId="false">
<div id="sharebtn">
                    <a class="button Share" style="" id="shareButton">Share</a>
                </div>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topicVO.body}" id="topic_body"/>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topicVO.videoAudioUrl}" id="topic_vaurl" />
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topic_guid}" id="topic_guid" />
        <p:commandLink id="commandLink" action="#{topicController.createTopic}"
                     </f:form>
```

**Error**

```
20:38:13,793 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/emyed-web].[default]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$SessionScopeHandler.handle(BeanManager.java:575) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.pushToScope(BeanManager.java:458) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:410) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.hasLoggedIn(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:113) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.doFilter(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:84) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
```

Comment: Looks like your error is the `<f:form>`, it should be `<h:form>` or maybe you just posted your code with errors.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually i am now not getting those errors if i changed to SessionScope rather than ViewScope.However, it is not sending the parameter values such as Topic_body and topic_vaurl to the server.

Comment: Why can't you use the ajax functionality that PrimeFaces `<p:commandButton>` offers? You should post your functional requirement to get better help.

Comment: @user1595858 you should set execute to "testForm" if you want other inputs, like topic_body and topic_vaurl to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to Filter class EmyEdAccessFilter failing. I got the right soultion fromm BalusC

[Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148019/servlet-service-for-servlet-faces-servlet-threw-exception-java-lang-nullpoint)

Answer (score 0):

If you want parameter values `Topic_body` and `topic_vaurl` to be sent to the server try following code:

`jsf.ajax.request('testForm',null,{execute: 'commandLink',render: 'topic_guid'});`

if it did not work replace `'testForm'` with `':testForm'`.