# Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a fix to the below error. When i click the command button it calls the java script to set the values for topic_body,topic_url and submit the values to a method in server by the commandbutton. I am not sure what was need to be corrected to stop the error.

**XHTML**

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="testForm">
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topicVO.body}" id="topic_body">
        </h:inputHidden>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topicVO.videoAudioUrl}" id="topic_vaurl" >
        </h:inputHidden>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{topicBean.topic_guid}" id="topic_guid">
        </h:inputHidden>
                <p:commandButton id="shareeButton" action="#{topicController.createTopic}" onclick="javascript:renderElement();">
                Share
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function  renderElement(){
           var textarea_content = $('textarea#wall').val();
           $('#topic_body').val(textarea_content);
           if (textarea_content != '') {
               var sitetitle = $('label.title').html();
               if (sitetitle == null) {
                   sitetitle = ' ';
               }
.......
......
..

}
```

**JSF Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "topicBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TopicBean extends BaseMB implements Serializable {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CircleBean.class.toString());
    private TopicVO topicVO = new TopicVO();
    private long topic_guid =0;
    public TopicBean(){
        logger.info("****************************Start TopicBean Constructor****************************************");
        logger.info("****************************End TopicBean Constructor****************************************");

    }
```

**JSF Method**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "topicController")
@RequestScoped
public class TopicController  extends BaseMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(CircleController.class.toString());
    TopicBean topicBean;


    public void createTopic(){
        logger.info("*******************Inside creatTopic********************");
        topicBean = (TopicBean) FacesUtils.getManagedBean("topicBean");
        ITopicService topicService = (ITopicService) ServiceLocator
                .getService("TOPICSERVICE");
         topicBean.setTopic_guid(topicService.createTopic(topicBean.getTopicVO(), userSession));

        logger.info("*******************Inside creatTopic********************");
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
14:44:20,335 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/emyed-web].[Faces Servlet]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$SessionScopeHandler.handle(BeanManager.java:575) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.pushToScope(BeanManager.java:458) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:410) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.hasLoggedIn(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:113) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.doFilter(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:84) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]



enter code here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the stacktrace,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$SessionScopeHandler.handle(BeanManager.java:575) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.pushToScope(BeanManager.java:458) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:410) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.hasLoggedIn(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:113) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.filter.EmyEdAccessFilter.doFilter(EmyEdAccessFilter.java:84) [emyed-ui-1.0.jar:]
```

you've a `Filter` class `EmyEdAccessFilter` which is trying to resolve a JSF-specific EL expression using `ValueExpression`, most likely with the sole purpose to find a session scoped JSF managed bean or its property which should represent the logged-in user. But this EL resolving failed because there's no means of a `FacesContext` inside a servlet filter. The `FacesContext` is supposed to be created by the `FacesServlet`, but at the moment the filter runs, the `FacesServlet` hasn't run at all and thus the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null` and thus your code breaks.

All with all, this is not the right way to check a session scoped JSF managed bean in a filter.

Under JSF's covers, session scoped managed beans are stored as attributes of the `HttpSession` with the managed bean name as session attribute name. You can just access them "the usual way" as session attributes in a servlet filter. E.g.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    UserManager userManager = (session != null) ? (UserManager) session.getAttribute("userManager") : null;

    if (userManager == null || !userManager.isLoggedIn()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
    }
}
```

Where `UserManager` represents your session scoped JSF managed bean.

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/2633733#2633733)

Answer (score 0):

Also check @ManagedProperty is correct. For example:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{user_ejb}")
UserEJB userEJB;
```

Or @Inject